# OperationVetoedException - when updating an existing (unique) document

Tags: .net, ravendb, unique-constraint

I am getting an OperationVetoedException when i try to update a document in my RavenDB database.

My version of RavenDB and the UniqueConstraintsBundle is 960 (and has always been, never updated from any previous version).

I have checked and I can't find any duplicates in the database. So I don't understand how this error could be possible.

The list oldVisitorSessions in my code example below contains only unique objects.

**Code**

```
using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    foreach (var visitorSession in oldVisitorSessions)
    {
        visitorSession.ProspectType = string.Empty;
        session.Store(visitorSession);
    }

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Exception**

```
Url: "/bulk_docs"
Raven.Database.Exceptions.OperationVetoedException: PUT vetoed by Raven.Bundles.UniqueConstraints.UniqueConstraintsPutTrigger because: Ensure unique constraint violated for fields: session_id
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.AssertPutOperationNotVetoed(String key, RavenJObject metadata, RavenJObject document, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 522
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass37.<Put>b__30(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 476
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 330
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Put(String key, Nullable`1 etag, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 468
   at Raven.Database.Extensions.CommandExtensions.Execute(ICommandData self, DocumentDatabase database) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Extensions\CommandExtensions.cs:line 25
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClassca.<Batch>b__c6(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 1196
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 376
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 337
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Batch(IEnumerable`1 commands) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 1192
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Batch(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line 94
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line 38
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 550
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 316
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have a unique constraint failure on 'session_id', it is likely that you have it set to null, right?
And there is another thing there that is also null.

Comment: No sorry, i tried the query:
session_id:[[NULL_VALUE]]
and it returned nothing. So it seems i have no nullvalues. The document also have nothing marked as nullable.